# C++ \n in a string (Not working)

Tags: c++, return, line

I'm learning C++. Here's my problem.

http://prntscr.com/2m5flm

I created a function who can read Prop files like them (you can set the file beginning and ending tags with a function, searching a specified tag with a function who will return a string (containing the results).

Here's the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "m_PFile_r.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    m_PFile_r k;
    k.open("prop.arg");
    k.imNotaFag(true);
    k.setOpenArg("$FILE_BEGIN$");
    k.setCloseArg("$FILE_END$");
    string lS;
    lS=k.getArg("launchSentence");
    cout << lS << endl;
    string menu;
    menu=k.getArg("progMenu");
    cout << menu;
    return 0;
}
```

**MY QUESTION IS : Why doesn't it print the \n as a line return ?**

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see any attempts to print "\n" in your code. Can you please specify where you are trying to print a \n

Comment: `imNotaFag`? Somebody's having a laugh!

Comment: WTH is `m_PFile_r`?? Cannot spot any attempt to output a `\n` anywhere besides that.

Answer (score 5):

The file has new line characters in it, they are defining the end of the lines.  When you enter the newline character in the file, it is being stored in that file not as a newline character, but the two individual characters "\" and "n".  So when you then read in the file, those characters are read in just like the others.

You are over complicating this problem.  If you would like to print out various phrases to the user, just include those phrases as string variables in your program.

`String launchSentence = "This is the launch sentence.";`

`String progMenu = "Hit 1 For Add Hit 2 for Subtract";`

These could then be printed with the normal COUT << progMenu method.

If your purpose with the text file is to keep all of the possible text strings isolated in one easy location, why not create a TextCommandPrompts.h, fill it with the String (character in C++) variables and include that in your main?

Edit - Because I can't comment yet and I want to respond to one  - I thought that whatever text editor that was letting him write line by line would be messing this up.  As in, its already doing the "\n" magic, and when he writes in the characters '\' and 'n' something mundane happened, and they stayed as regular characters.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down, as it's correct.  The characters "\" and "n" in sequence (in a text file) won't get magically turned into a newline.  The code must recognise them, and replace them with a real newline before display.

Comment: Okay, how to change that ?

Comment: What?  When you write a `'\n'` to a file, the implementation does treat it special, but how depends on the implementation, and I don't know of any which convert it into the two character sequence \, n.

Comment: @JamesKanze the problem is that his input textfile contains "\n" (as two chars) not the literal '\n' character.

Comment: @user3232822 You'll need to parse your string, find any "\n"s (two chars) and replace them with real '\n's (since return char).  If you're on Windows you'll probably actually want \r\n anyway.

Comment: @benjymous Why didn't he say so?  (And even on Windows, if you're outputting through a text stream, you want `'\n'`, and `'\n'` only.  But since he doesn't actually say anything about what he's doing, who knows?)